# Understanding a use of the supremum in this proof of weak maximum principle

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, supremum-and-infimum

> **Theorem 5 (Weak Maximum Principle)**
>   Suppose that $\Omega$ is bounded and that $L$ is strictly elliptic with $c \leq 0$.
>   If $u \in C^2(\Omega) \cap C(\bar{\Omega})$ and $L u \geq 0$ in $\Omega$, then a nonnegative maximum is attained at the boundary.
>
> **Proof.**
>   Suppose that $\Omega \subset \{|x_1|  < d\}$.
>   Consider $w(x) = u(x) + \varepsilon e^{\alpha x_1}$ with $\varepsilon > 0$.
>   Then
>   \begin{align*}
>         L w
>   &=    Lu
>         + \varepsilon
>           \left( \alpha^2 a_{11}(x) + \alpha b_1(x) + c(x) \right)
>           e^{\alpha x_1} \\
>   &\geq \varepsilon
>         \left(
>           \alpha^2 \lambda - \alpha \| b_1 \|_\infty - \| c \|_\infty 
>         \right)
>         e^{\alpha x_1}.
> \end{align*}
>   One chooses $\alpha$ large enough to find $L w > 0$.
>   By the previous lemma $w$ cannot have a nonnegative maximum $\Omega$.
>   Hence
>   $$
>         \sup_\Omega u
>   \leq  \sup_\Omega w
>   \leq  \sup_\Omega w^+
>   =     \sup_{\partial \Omega} w^+
>   \leq  \sup_{\partial \Omega} u^+ + \varepsilon e^{\alpha d}.
> $$
>
> (Original image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGzQs.png).)

I'm reading this proof of the weak maximum principle. The operator $L$ is this one:

$$L = \sum a_{jk}(x)\partial_j\partial_k + \sum b_j\partial_j$$

but I don't think it's relevant for what I'll ask. I understood everything except for the $\sup$ arguments.

It's natural that $\sup_{\Omega}u\le \sup_{\Omega}w$ since $w = u + \epsilon\mbox{ something positive}$. Now, what does $\sup_{\Omega}w^{+}$ mean? What does the plus sign mean and why $\sup_{\Omega}w^{}\le \sup_{\Omega}w^{+}$? Why, also, $\sup_{\Omega}w^{+} = \sup_{\partial\Omega}w^{+}$.

Why, also, the argument concludes if we let $\varepsilon\to 0$?

Where is used the hypothesis of maximum not existing in $\Omega$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theorem is stated incorrectly.
In particular, consider the simple counter-example $u = -1$.
In this case, $Lu = -c \geq 0$ and clearly $u$ does not attain a nonnegative maximum.

Below is the correct statement with a very detailed proof that should answer all of your questions.

**Theorem 5 (Weak Maximum Principle)** Suppose that $\Omega$ is bounded and that $L$ is strictly elliptic with $c\leq0$.
If $u\in C^{2}(\Omega)\cup C(\overline{\Omega})$, $Lu\geq0$ in $\Omega$, and $\color{blue}{u\geq0 \text{ on } \partial \Omega}$, then a nonnegative maximum is attained at the boundary.

In the proof, we use the notation $a^{+}=\max\{a,0\}$.

*Proof*.
Let $\epsilon>0$ and $w(x)=\epsilon e^{\alpha x_{1}}+u(x)$.
Then,
\begin{multline*}
Lw(x)=\epsilon L[e^{\alpha x_{1}}](x)+Lu(x)\geq\epsilon L[e^{\alpha x_{1}}](x)\\
=\epsilon\left(\alpha^{2}a_{11}(x)+\alpha b_{1}(x)+c(x)\right)e^{\alpha x_{1}}\geq\epsilon\left(\alpha^{2}\lambda-\alpha\left\Vert b_{1}\right\Vert _{\infty}-\left\Vert c\right\Vert _{\infty}\right)e^{\alpha x_{1}}.
\end{multline*}
Since $\lambda>0$, we can always pick $\alpha$ large enough for $Lw>0$ to hold on all of $\Omega$.

Applying Lemma 4 of http://www.mi.uni-koeln.de/~gsweers/pdf/maxprinc.pdf,  $w$ cannot attain a nonnegative maximum in $\Omega$.
As a result of this, $w^{+}$ cannot attain a maximum in $\Omega$ since then $w$ would attain a nonnegative maximum in $\Omega$.
We summarize this by writing $\sup_{\Omega}w^{+}=\sup_{\partial\Omega}w^{+}$.

Next, note that
$$
w^{+}=(u+\epsilon e^{\alpha x_{1}})^{+}\leq u^{+}+(\epsilon e^{\alpha x_{1}})^{+}=u^{+}+\epsilon e^{\alpha x_{1}}.
$$
Using the boundedness of $\Omega$, this implies that $\sup_{\partial\Omega}w^{+}\leq\sup_{\partial\Omega}u^{+}+\epsilon c$ for some large enough $c$.
Letting $\epsilon\rightarrow0$, we have $\sup_{\partial\Omega}w^{+}\leq\sup_{\partial\Omega}u^{+}$.

Lastly, since $u\leq w\leq w^{+}$, we can combine the inequalities in the previous two paragraphs to get $\sup_{\Omega}u\leq\sup_{\partial\Omega}u^{+}$.
Since $u\geq0$ on $\partial\Omega$, we have $\sup_{\partial\Omega}u^{+}=\sup_{\partial\Omega}u$.
Putting this all together,
$$
\sup_{\Omega}u\leq\sup_{\partial\Omega}u
$$
as desired. ∎

Comment: Why $\max\{w,0\}$ is needed? I guess it has something to do with the boundary

Comment: page 2: http://www.mi.uni-koeln.de/~gsweers/pdf/maxprinc.pdf

Comment: Could you explain why $w$ having no local maximum implies that values on the boundary are greater than on the interior?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs: I had some free time so I updated my answer. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: I' reviewing the answer and will accept it soon, thank you so much